# Can't figure the reason of increased page width

Tags: css

My webpage http://www.pointmovies.com/ is showing scroll bar at the bottom and it looks like it has so much empty space on the right side. I can't figure out what is increasing the width of my page and how can I remove this.

It is wordpress, every post is an article (image) having width of 18% and float left, so on one row 5 posts/articles will display. But because of this 18% width I see that my page width increased. When I remove this 18% from the article css, page go to normal.

This is the css for article

```
width: 18%;
float: left;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 21px;
min-height: 400px;
```

Here is the screenshot. Please check the below scroll bar which should not be there.
[image]

Comment: It looks fine to me - can you provide a contained example of the problem you are facing or some screenshots?

Comment: I can see the issue

Comment: `#main { overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: I just added the screenshot of the issue.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman posted the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
#main {
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

to your css.

For your other issue.
The Style for the first div after #main should looks like this. That is why your site is not going responsive properly.

```
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
max-width: 1170px;
display: inline;
```

Tamoor, the `overflow-X` disables it from left to right.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @norcal johnny. This is great help for me. I was looking for solution for more than 10 days. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help. Glad it worked out. Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Add this CSS to fix it:

```
#page{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Not the best solution, it will not show the scrollbar if the window gets too small

Comment: @Flink, I applied that and noticed this that it will never display scrollbar. Any solution for this?

Comment: I only noticed, that the total width depends on the 18% of the articles. Maybe wrap all your articles in another div and play around with that div.